# ajax response always give error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some problem with ajax response my ajax code give right result but in ajax code it goes always in error condition.

here is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseURL+"top_ten_wikilerter",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(resp){
            alert('eror');
        }
   });
```

when i print the result in php end it gives

```
<div class="row tpbtm-pdng brdr-btm">
<a href="#"> 
   <div class="col-md-5"> 
       <div class="col-md-2"><img src="/assets/images/users/user1.png" class="img-circle"  /></div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">Sandy</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7" id="rght-sd-icn">
                        <div class="col-md-2"><span ref="tooltip" data-toggle="" data-placement="top" title="This user has reported 7 alerts">
                                <img src="/assets/images/icons/alert.png"/>
                                <span>7</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <span ref="tooltip" data-toggle="" data-placement="top" title="This user has reviewed 2 alerts">
                                <img src="/assets/images/icons/copy-search.png" />
                                <span>2</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3"><span ref="tooltip" data-toggle="" data-placement="top" title="This user has informed or help to inform 2 users">   
                                <img src="/assets/images/icons/find-frnd.png" />
                                <span>2</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5"><img src="/uploads/user_type_icon/Graduate1410251236.png" /><span class="dmigd-text">Graduate</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

after execute code in php end it give result but in ajax response it goes always in error condition.

Comment: do u get response in json format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **datatype** should be **html** not **json** because the response which you are getting is **html** not **json** so correct ajax request as shown below :-

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: baseURL+"top_ten_wikilerter",
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(resp){
          alert('success');
     },
     error: function(resp){
          alert('eror');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX code you are passing JSON data, but you return HTML. That is a type error, you need to same dataType in both the AJAX request and PHP end.